# tlink error: <filename>.asm : bad object file

Tags: assembly, x86, linker, tasm

I am using a TASM assembler version from the following site, which is a separately configured version created for 64 bit Windows:
https://techapple.net/2013/01/tasm-windows-7-windows-8-full-screen-64bit-version-single-installer/#comment-187611

The following code(addbyte.asm) simply adds two numbers.

I compiled it with

> tasm addbyte.asm

and it compiles without a problem.

```
data segment
num1 db 05h
num2 db 05h
result db ?
data ends

code segment
assume ds:data, cs:code
start:
mov ax,data
mov ds,ax
mov al,num1
mov bl,num2
add al,bl
mov result,ah
mov ah,4ch
int 21
code ends
end start
end
```

But it is when I try to link it as...

> tlink addbyte.asm

or

> tlink addbyte.obj

it says:

> addbyte.asm : bad object file

Update: I tried `tlink addbyte.obj` and i get the following result:

[image]

[image]

I've never ever written a line of assembly code before this, I'm just following my instructor and she suggested to use this assembler for compiling x86 assembly code. I'm not sure what is happening over here. I'm just stuck over here. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You first have to assemble with `tasm addbyte.asm` to get the obj (object file) and then link with `tlink addbyte.obj`  that should create `addbyte.exe`

Comment: @MichaelPetch I'm sorry for not making it clear that I have compiled it before linking it.

Comment: Diksha, that TD window looks like you've just invoked it with `td` on its own. Have you tried running `td addbytes`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tlink` program is a *linker,* something capable of taking binary files that have *already* been assembled or compiled, and making an executable file from them. You will need to run your source code through an *assembler* in order to get a binary assembled file, that's the `tasm` program.

The process is basically:

```
asmSource -> TASM -> objFile -> TLINK -> exeFile
```

(though with the possibility of `tlink` taking *multiple* object files or a compiler taking a higher-level language to turn it into an object file):

```
asmSource -> TASM -----> objFile
                                \
                                 >-> TLINK -> exeFile
                                /
hllSource -> COMPILER -> objFile
```

In fact, the link you posted actually *contains* this information (paraphrased):

- For compiling, `tasm filename.asm`
- For linking, `tlink filename.obj`
- For debugger, `td` or `td filename`
- For Execution, `filename.exe`

In your *particular* case, you'll probably find that this sequence works (minus the comments on the right):

```
tasm addbyte.asm    # to assemble.
tlink addbyte.obj   # to link.
addbyte.exe         # to run.
td addbyte.exe      # to debug.
```

By way of example, here's a snapshot of correct assembling, linking, and running of the sample `add2` program distributed with that package (though, if the intent is to add two numbers, it's not a very *good* program):

[image]

---

And, just an an aside, I'm not sure how wise it is to actually *use* `tasm`. I know that DosBox is free for any use, but `tasm` itself was very much a commercial product that may still be subject to copyright restrictions. From memory, it passed from Borland to Inprise to Codegear, then I think it ended up with Embarcadero, though they make no mention of it on their web site so I can't be sure. I actually *have* a legal copy since I'm the type to never throw *anything* away, much to the disdain of my wife :-)

Now you *may* be okay (that's not legal advice, by the way) but you're probably better off playing it safe and finding another assembler for your purposes, like the [Netwide Assembler](https://www.nasm.us/), or [Yasm](https://yasm.tortall.net/).

Comment: If one is not using TASM ideal mode and you want a MASM compatible assembler then JWASM works well. It is quite compatible (except for the cmd line options) and available under an open source license (Sybase/Watcom). https://www.japheth.de/JWasm.html. It is available for most OSes (linux/MacOS/DOS/Windows) and is likely available with a Linux distro package manager. There is a JWLINK linker, although the assembler has the ability to output a DOS MZ or COM program directly without a linker. A DOS MZ program could be generated with `jwasm -mz addbyte.asm` which produces addbyte.exe

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, actually I found out that it also works for "tlink addbyte" and "td addbyte". thanks for suggesting the assemblers too both of you :)